# Иногда аватары показываются криво в очередях проверок

Tags: дефект, дизайн, очередь-проверок

Если у участника "нет" аватара (т.е. показывается стандартное `<ИМЯ>'s user avatar`) и имя довольно длинное, то аватар некрасиво вылезает за линию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может, это надо постить на MSE?

---

ОС - Windows 10;
Браузер - Firefox 113.0;
Размер экрана - 1920×1080 (браузер открыт на весь экран).

Comment: хорошо бы ссылку на проверку и можно на MSE

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вот ссылка на вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1098949/

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ответа уже нет, который надо было проверять.

Comment: Ссылка на проверку всё равно остаётся, даже если пост удаляется. [Вот эта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/860337), видимо.

Comment: Надо в вопрос еще версию браузера, ОС добавить и размер окна. @insolor там аватар, заблокированный на территории какой-то страны?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ обычно аватары с facebook не видны в РФ. В данном случае похоже другая проблема, видимо пользователь удалил или просто заменил свой аватар в гугле (скорее всего регистрировался на so через гугл, поэтому аватар оттуда подтягивается): https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTIbP.png. Чтобы такая проблема не возникала, нужно чтобы SO хранил аватары у себя, а не хранил просто ссылки на сторонние сайты.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, добавил нужную информацию.